# NHibernate: unexpected behavior when querying for an unmapped entity

Tags: nhibernate, exception

I have a generic Repository class that wrap an Nhibernate session:

```
public class Repository<T>{

public IQueryable<T> GetAll(){

    return this.Session.Query<T>();
}

}
```

Despite the fact that I had data in the underlying DB table mapped to entity `Foo`, calling `Repository.GetAll<Foo>()` returned an empty enumerable.  After much consternation, I found the issue to be that I had forgotten to load my class mapping into the SessionFactory.

I was floored that NHibernate does not throw an exception when attempting to load an entity type for which it has no mapping.  This feels like **exactly the kind of scenario** that should cause NH to fail early **and** loudly.

Here's the code that bootstraps NH.  Notice the two lines loading the mapping were commented out

```
 private static Configuration BuildNHibernateConfig(Action<IDbIntegrationConfigurationProperties> dbIntegration)
        {
            var configuration = new Configuration();

            configuration
                .Proxy(p => p.ProxyFactoryFactory<DefaultProxyFactoryFactory>())
                .DataBaseIntegration(db =>
                {

                    db.ConnectionString = connectionString.Value;
                    db.Dialect<MsSql2008Dialect>();

                })
                .AddAssembly(typeof(ActionConfirmation<>).Assembly)
                .SetProperty("show_sql", "true")

                .CurrentSessionContext<LazySessionContext>();

         //   var mappings = GetMappings();
         //   configuration.AddDeserializedMapping(mappings, "Hydra");

            return configuration;
        }

        private static HbmMapping GetMappings()
        {
            var mapper = new ModelMapper();
            mapper.AddMapping<FacilityMap>();
            return mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();

        }
```

Is this normal behavior or I have somehow misconfigured NH?  Is there a way to override this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LINQ implementation is a wrapper of the Criteria API and this issue [has been reported](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2183) and marked as "won't fix". The comment from Fabio Maulo indicates that verifying that the class is mapped was too much of a performance hit.

This was news to me as well and I at first assumed it was due to LINQ deferred execution.

Comment: NH-LINQ _WAS_ a wrapper of the criteria API. Since NH 3.0 the LINQ provider is based on the HQL engine.

Comment: Another point is that it's possible to do e.g.. Query<UnmappedBaseType>() and the query will include all mapped subclasses.